# Is the python function 're.finditer()' made in python language or java or c language?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

```
import re
txt = 'hello world'
def findo_bjects(word, path): return [call for call in re.finditer(word, path)]
print(findo_bjects('hello', txt))
```

I'm wondering if 're.finditer()' function is made in `c programming` or `python` or `java` ?

Comment: are all the regex functions made in c language ?

Answer (score 0):

It is mostly written in C.

some history is here: https://etutorials.org/Programming/Python.+Text+processing/Chapter+3.+Regular+Expressions/3.3+Standard+Modules/

and the source code is here:

https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/main/Modules/_sre

Comment: also the next() function ?